# What is the probability that there will be 1 ministerial position with two claims, 1 position with no claims, and 8 positions with one claim?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, combinations

I have a question regarding a counting problem:

a)Within the coalition of five parties ten ministerial positions must be divided between the parties. Each party is allowed to claim two such positions, so in total ten claims are submitted for ten positions. Assume that each party claims two different positions at random. Ideally all ten claims will turn out to be different, so that there will be no problem in determining which party gets which ministerial positions. What is the probability that this ideal situation will occur?

b)What is the probability that there will be 1 ministerial position with two claims, 1 position with no claims, and 8 positions with one claim?

I understood part a), but I do not understand how to find the answer to part b)

for part a) I represented the 10 ministerial positions with letters to distribute them over the 5 parties. So in this case; AA BB CC DD EE

now to divide them I did (10 choose 2) (8 choose 2) (6 choose 2) (4 choose 2) / (10 choose 2) ^5
For part b however, I am confused. I did

T T O O O O O O O O, to represent with letters that the first ministerial position got 2 claims, and the other eight got 1 claim, and one position got zero claims (no letter)

Now the way I tried to find the probability that this situation occurs is

(10 choose 2) *(choose 2 out of 10 claims that are for 1 position)* * (8 choose 8) *10 (first claim can be divided over 10 positions) * 8 (second claim can be divided over 8 positions), but for the rest I am lost.

I added the solution to the question which I also do not understand.

[image]

Comment: Each particular "Claim" is equally probable, where a claim means an ordered $10-$tuple of choices.  Thus you just need to count the claims that pass the test you have in mind.

Comment: Correction:  it's slightly more complicated than I suggested, since the two members of a given party can't both choose the same slot.  So you need to add that constraint from the start.

Answer (score 1):

There are $10$ ways to choose the doubly picked position, $9$ ways to choose the position not picked at all, and $\binom52=10$ ways to pick the two parties $A$ and $B$ that picked the doubly picked position.

For each of these choices, the probability that $A$ picked the doubly picked position and one of the $8$ singletons is $\frac8{45}$, the probability that $B$ picked the doubly picked position and one of the remaining $7$ singletons is $\frac7{45}$, and the probability that the other $3$ parties picked the remaining $6$ singletons without duplication is $\frac{6!}{90^3}$, so overall the probability is

$$
10\cdot9\cdot10\cdot\frac8{45}\cdot\frac7{45}\cdot\frac{6!}{90^3}=40\cdot\frac{10!}{90^5}=\frac{448}{18225}\approx2.46\%\;.
$$